# How to compute bitwise-or on the segment fast?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, prefix-sum

Given a list of integers.

I wonder if it is possible to calculate bitwise OR on the segment for O(1) per query and O(n) of the premise? (Some prefix sums) (it is Easy to do this for O(log n) per query and O(n log n) of the premise, for example, using the segment tree, but what is faster?)

Comment: What do you mean? Given a list of integer or boolean values, you want the `or` (logical or bitwise) of a specific subsegment, e.g. `a[3] | a[4] | a[5]`? Can you add an example?

Comment: list of integers. bitwise or

Comment: I can also think of a way with O(logn) per query and O(nlogn) preprocessing, by accumulating how often each bit has been set for all values in the list, then checking for which the values are higher in the upper bound number than in the lower bound. Don't think there's a way with O(1) per query + O(n) preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Just build a prefix-sum-like array for each bit position and fill it with a running total of bits set from the start of your data. The initial value for each counter would be zero: `counter[0][b]=0`, and the `n`-th counter would store a number of bits set in data items 0 through n-1.

Then you can test if the bit no `b` is set anywhere in the given range `[m,n]`  just by testing if `b`-th counters on both ends of the range differ (`counter[n+1][b] not.eq. counter[m][b]`).

Finally compose an answer bit by bit from results of all (8, 16, 32...) bit positions.

Be aware this solution requires an additional integer per each bit of original data, which means you need e.g. 32 times more memory if  your int is 32 bits wide.

Comment: This is basically what I described in comments. I would not classify this as O(1) though, but rather O(logn). Both is somewhat debatable. You could say O(1) since the number of bits for e.g. an `int64` is constant, I would say it is `logn` assuming the number of bits in the values in the list is somewhat related to the total number of elements in the list. Of course, for arbitrary-size numbers neither is correct and it should just be O(b) where b is the maximum number of bits.

Comment: It's a bit of nitpicking, isn't it? Going that way you could also say the addition 'n+1' is O(log n) because in the worst case we need to carry a bit overflow through all bits of the left-side operand.  In practice, however, we work within arbitrary but _constant_ technical constraints, which make a width of an integer constant; also addition, comparison and other basic operations are considered constant-time.

Comment: When you code a problem like this, you usually know, or you can choose, what size of integer you handle. And this becomes constant. You usually treat the length of list as a variable parameter, to which the O() estimations refer.

Comment: For a prefix-sum method to be efficient we need a fast random access. This requires an array. The array is usually indexed with some integer type, sometimes platform-dependent. Then we know in advance a maximum number of bits, hence a required size of each counter.

Comment: @tobias_k Pinging (forgot it before).

Comment: I did not want to be picky, just to point out that I am not sure if this is really O(1), or if OP would consider this O(1) or O(logn). Pretty sure that addition is actually done in a single operation on modern CPUs though, whereas this would have to be a real loop in the program, so IMHO that comparison does not really hold. But again, I do not say that this is a bad solution. In fact, it's probably as good as it gets.

Comment: I don't think it's O(1) too. Оn the contrary, I think it's the most obvious way to solve this problem.